# Printing out the perfect numbers between a specific interval

Tags: c

```
// starting, end,  number, sum of the divisor, delimiter 
int pocetok, kraj, broj,   zbir_na_deliteli=0, delitel=1;
printf("Vnesi go intervalot: ");  // Enter the interval
scanf("%d%d", &pocetok, &kraj);

for(broj=pocetok;broj<=kraj;broj++)
    for(;delitel<broj;delitel++){
        if(broj%delitel==0)
            zbir_na_deliteli+=delitel;
    }
    if(zbir_na_deliteli==broj)
        // The number %d is a perfect number
        printf("Brojot %d e sovrshen broj\n", broj);
    }
```

This is the program I wrote. I am literally comparing it line by line with a solved program that does the exact same thing except that one works but this one doesn't.

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing `delitel = 1;` inside a loop, perhaps?

Comment: Try `for(;delitel<broj;delitel++){` --> `for(int delitel = 1;delitel<broj;delitel++){`

Comment: No, it's initialized in the first line. It's not needed to be where the beginning value is supposed to be in the the for loop. I'm not getting an error ether. @pmg

Comment: Yeah, it's needed, because you do `zbir_na_deliteli+=delitel`.  Why not just `zbir_na_deliteli++`??  I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to calculate, since I don't know what your variable names mean.  Looks like you're just trying to count them.  But your question says "print out the numbers".  You only print something once, after all the loops.  Perhaps you are missing some `{` `}`

Comment: zbir_na_deliteli+=delitel is to sum up the denominators for the number. I can't sum them up if i increment them by 1 @paddy

Comment: Right, so then shouldn't it be set to 1 before the inner loop each time around?

Comment: Spyware, The [Missing delitel = 1; inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016104/printing-out-the-perfect-numbers-between-a-specific-interval#comment92935869_53016104) refers to `delitel = 1;` inside `for(broj=pocetok....`, not inside `for(;delitel<broj...`.

Comment: @chux i thought you couldn't declare variables inside your for loop in c. At least that's what my college professor said.

Comment: You don't have to _declare_ it there.  You just need to set the value.  `for(delitel=1;delitel<broj;delitel++)`

Comment: Spyware, What compiler error or run time result did you get with `for(int delitel = 1;delitel<broj;delitel++){` ?

Comment: Spyware, "you couldn't declare variables inside your for loop in c. " is a not OK for pre C99 code.  OK to do so for the last 19 years.

Comment: @chux i'm not getting an error. The program is executing, but after i enter the beginning and ending value, it doesn't print out anything. I did put my 'delitel=1' inside the for loop like you said.

Comment: "but after i enter the beginning and ending value" --> why the secrecy?  What input values, what output was expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

**Counter `delitel` needs to restart at 1 each loop**

```
    // for(;delitel<broj;delitel++){
    for (int delitel = 1; delitel < broj; delitel++) {
```

**Sum `zbir_na_deliteli` needs to be reset to 0 each loop**

```
  for (int broj = pocetok; broj <= kraj; broj++) {
    int zbir_na_deliteli = 0;
```

Sample code:

```
void Printing_out_the_perfect_numbers(int pocetok, int kraj) {
  for (int broj = pocetok; broj <= kraj; broj++) {
    int zbir_na_deliteli = 0;
    for (int delitel = 1; delitel < broj; delitel++) {
      if (broj % delitel == 0) {
        zbir_na_deliteli += delitel;
      }
    }
    if (zbir_na_deliteli == broj) {
      printf("Brojot %d e sovrshen broj\n", broj);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  Printing_out_the_perfect_numbers(1, 10000);
}
```

Output

```
Brojot 6 e sovrshen broj
Brojot 28 e sovrshen broj
Brojot 496 e sovrshen broj
Brojot 8128 e sovrshen broj
```

---

A faster approach would not test division up to `broj`, but the the square root of `broj`.  Rather than calculate the square root directly, keep track of the quotient as well as the remainder.  Many compilers, will provide the quotient and remainder (`%` and `/`) with one calculation so not to incur an extra expensive division.

```
void Printing_out_the_perfect_numbers(int pocetok, int kraj) {
  for (int broj = pocetok; broj <= kraj; broj++) {
    int zbir_na_deliteli = 0;
    int kvocient = broj;
    for (int delitel = 1; delitel < kvocient; delitel++) {
      if (broj % delitel == 0) {
        kvocient = broj / delitel;
        zbir_na_deliteli += delitel;
        if (kvocient > delitel) {
          if (delitel != 1) zbir_na_deliteli += kvocient;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (zbir_na_deliteli == broj) {
      printf("Brojot %d e sovrshen broj\n", broj);
    }
  }
}
```

---

See [Perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) and [Pernicious number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pernicious_number)

Comment: is the second answer faster in terms of run time?

Comment: @Spyware Yes, its faster.  As `n` increase, it is much faster.  Yet even faster methods exist.